# auth0-java v1.0.0 fails with error 400: User is not authorized to the audience for those scopes

Tags: java, authentication, auth0

I'm trying to develop a microservice to handle authentication wiht Auth0.

I have added the auth0-java dependency in its last version :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>auth0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The service should take the user/pwd and verify it on Auth0 and send back the AccessToken.

Here is the failing code :

```
    AuthAPI auth = new AuthAPI("my-domain.auth0.com", "xxx", "yyy");
    AuthRequest request = auth.login(username, password, "Username-Password-Authentication")
            .setAudience("https://my-domain.auth0.com/api/v2/")
            .setScope("openid name email app_metadata");
    try {
        TokenHolder holder = request.execute();
        return holder;
    } catch (Auth0Exception e) {
        throw new AuthentException("Error authenticating " + username, e);
    }
```

This code fails with :

> Request failed with status code 400: User is not authorized to the audience for those scopes

I tried with scopes like "read:client read:user", etc... but same problem.

I then tried with older version 0.4.0, and it works.

Here is the working code :

```
    Auth0 auth = new Auth0("xxx", "my-domain.auth0.com");
    AuthenticationAPIClient client = auth.newAuthenticationAPIClient();
    try {
        Authentication execute = client.getProfileAfter(client.login(username, password)
                .setConnection("Username-Password-Authentication")).setScope("openid name email app_metadata").execute();
        return execute.getCredentials();
    } catch (APIException e) {
        throw new AuthentException("Error authenticating " + username, e);
    }
```

So why does the 0.4.0 works, and not the 1.0.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 1.0.0 you are trying to authenticate a user for management API. You can not authenticate a user against management API. Auth0 management API only allows authentication via `client credentials` grant [reference](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/tokens)

With 0.4.0 code snippet, by calling `login` api, you are authenticating user with `password` grant.

To authenticate a user with password grant with 1.0.0 version you can use the same snippet, however set the audience to the Resource Server (API) of your own for eg. `https://example.com/api`. Or if you do not want to get an access token for a specific audience then use simpler login api [reference](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/auth0/client/auth/AuthAPI.java#L296)

Comment: Thx, I had to set the default directory to "Username-Password-Authentication", but then it works.

Comment: Do you know how to get the user_metadata and app_metadata in v1.0.0 ? When i use `scope="openid name email app_metadata user_metadata"` it works with 0.4.0 code, but not in 1.0.0 code. It sends just the openid, name and email infos.

Comment: Is your client marked as OIDC Conformant? (Tip: You can check that from Dashboard > Client > Settings > Advanced Settings > OAuth tab) If so then you will only get OIDC standard claims in the id_token. If you need custom claims you can add them to the id_token with a rule. Refer [here](https://auth0.com/docs/scopes/preview#custom-claims) for more details